# Numpy Sinus Behavior for different arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, trigonometry, linspace

Hello depending on the array I put into sinus I get a completely different output. test1, test3 are examples where it is not working. What's going on here?

```
test1 = np.sin(50.*2.*np.pi*np.arange(0., 512., dtype=np.float64))
test2 = np.sin(50.*2.*np.pi*np.linspace(0., 512., 512, endpoint=True, dtype=np.float64))
test3 = np.sin(50.*2.*np.pi*np.linspace(0., 512., 512, endpoint=False, dtype=np.float64))

plt.plot(np.arange(0, 512), test1)
plt.plot(np.arange(0, 512), test2)
plt.plot(np.arange(0, 512), test3)
plt.show()
```

**Edit:** Ok after doing some further research, here is the actual problem: Using test1 and test3 I violate the Nyquist Theorem and sample only values around zero. To resolve this issue one needs to increase either the sampling rate or decrease the frequency.

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: The expected output should look like test2. It's a normal sine wave with a frequency of 50/512.

Comment: Understood. I think I know what the issue could be and I posted it as my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I really think the problem is linked to the np.sin... The input values of from np.linspace/np.arange are similiar. The output of the sine is completely different.

Comment: I updated my answer. Does the explanation help?

Comment: Thanks Rahul, not quite I edited the question above. I was violating the Nyquist Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is that you expect `numpy.sin` to take in the angle in `degrees` as the argument but the documentation specifies that it takes in `radians`.

It looks like the numbers are being plotted as expected. One way to visualize all three plots i.e. test1, test2 and test3 is to use subplots:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test1 = np.sin(50.*2.*np.pi*np.arange(0., 512., dtype=np.float64))
test2 = np.sin(50.*2.*np.pi*np.linspace(0., 512., 512, endpoint=True, dtype=np.float64))
test3 = np.sin(50.*2.*np.pi*np.linspace(0., 512., 512, endpoint=False, dtype=np.float64))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0})

axs[0].plot(np.arange(0, 512), test1)
axs[1].plot(np.arange(0, 512), test2)
axs[2].plot(np.arange(0, 512), test3)
plt.show()
```

When you do the following:

```
print(f"Max of test1: {max(test1)}\nMin of test1: {min(test1)}")
print(f"Max of test2: {max(test2)}\nMin of test2: {min(test2)}")
print(f"Max of test3: {max(test3)}\nMin of test3: {min(test3)}")
```

**Output**

```
Max of test1: 1.4412955306804755e-11
Min of test1: -1.2978086425591747e-11
Max of test2: 0.9999952753720377
Min of test2: -0.9999952753719793
Max of test3: 1.4412955306804755e-11
Min of test3: -1.2978086425591747e-11
```

**Possible Solution**

The issue to me looks like the y limits on the graph are between -1 to 1 which is too high to visualize test1 and test3 (legibly). If you want to look at test1 and test3 in more detail (on the graph) you can do this:

```
test1 = np.sin(50.*2.*np.pi*np.arange(0., 512., dtype=np.float64))
test2 = np.sin(50.*2.*np.pi*np.linspace(0., 512., 512, endpoint=True, dtype=np.float64))
test3 = np.sin(50.*2.*np.pi*np.linspace(0., 512., 512, endpoint=False, dtype=np.float64))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0})

axs[0].set_ylim((min(test1), max(test1)))
axs[0].plot(np.arange(0, 512), test1)
axs[1].plot(np.arange(0, 512), test2)
axs[2].set_ylim((min(test1), max(test1)))
axs[2].plot(np.arange(0, 512), test3)
plt.show()
```

**Additional explanation**

Per the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sin.html) of `numpy.sin`, the argument it takes as x is the angle in `radians`, not to be confused with `degrees`.

Another point to note from the `numpy.linspace` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) is that

> Note that the step size changes when endpoint is False.

Here is a quick example:

```
np.linspace(0., 512., 5, endpoint=True, dtype=np.float64)
```

**Output**

```
array([  0., 128., 256., 384., 512.])
```

and

```
np.linspace(0., 512., 5, endpoint=False, dtype=np.float64)
```

**Output**

```
array([  0. , 102.4, 204.8, 307.2, 409.6])
```

Now, if do a quick check on `numpy.sin` on the highest values in each array i.e. 512. and 409.6

```
np.sin(409.6)
```

Output

```
0.9294631796005904
```

and

```
np.sin(512)
```

Output

```
0.07951849401287635
```

Hence, the difference.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But why is the result of test1 and test3 so different to test2? Given similar values? Expect the endpoint of linspace?

Comment: @user1536844 Updated my answer. The step size changes when the endpoint is false and numpy.sin takes the values in radians. The answers are showing up as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is not sinus behaviour. I reduced the size and printed the arrays that you feed to `np.sin()`.

```py
import numpy as np

SIZE = 4

print(np.arange(0., float(SIZE), dtype=np.float64))
print(np.linspace(0., float(SIZE), SIZE, endpoint=True, dtype=np.float64))
print(np.linspace(0., float(SIZE), SIZE, endpoint=False, dtype=np.float64))
```

The difference is pretty clear now. By changing endpoint you change boundaries of values, so you change step and thus all the values.

```
[0. 1. 2. 3.]
[0. 1.33333333 2.66666667 4.]
[0. 1. 2. 3.]
```

So sine gives differen outpt.

Comment: Tank you I know that. But why is the sine output completely different. It does not look like a sine - Given the quite similar inputs.